# scipy.optimize.minimize does not stop at maxiter or callback

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I've implemented scipy.optimize.minimize to minimize the mean of delta values of a pandas data frame for a 1D Array with 128 values.

It seems to run and do stuff, but it doesn't stop at `maxiter` or at a callback function taken from another Stack Overflow question here.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen
import time
import warnings

class TookTooLong(Warning):
    pass

class MinimizeStopper(object):
    def __init__(self, max_sec=60*60*5):
        self.max_sec = max_sec
        self.start = time.time()
    def __call__(self, xk=None):
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start
        if elapsed > self.max_sec:
            warnings.warn("Terminating optimization: time limit reached",
                          TookTooLong)
        else:
            # you might want to report other stuff here
            print("Elapsed: %.3f sec" % elapsed)

import scipy.optimize
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(minFunct,oned,options= 
            {"disp":True,"maxiter":100},tol=0.01,
                     method ="BFGS",callback=MinimizeStopper(1E-3))
```

The displayed message after some time tells me that `maxiter` has been reached and a smaller function value than at the start has been reached, but it just doesn't stop. Since it is running in jupyter, I have no way to reach `res` without the cell finishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) callback should be a callable returning `True` for termination and having the following format `callback(xk)`. Whereas in your code, you are defining it as an initialization of your class. Instead, you should define an instance of your class then assign its `__call__()` function to `callback` like the following:

```py
import time
import warnings
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen

class TookTooLong(Warning):
    pass

class MinimizeStopper(object):
    def __init__(self, max_sec=10):
        self.max_sec = max_sec
        self.start   = time.time()

    def __call__(self, xk):
        # callback to terminate if max_sec exceeded
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start
        if elapsed > self.max_sec:
            warnings.warn("Terminating optimization: time limit reached",
                          TookTooLong)
        else:
            # you might want to report other stuff here
            print("Elapsed: %.3f sec" % elapsed)
# init stopper
minimize_stopper = MinimizeStopper()
# minimze
res = minimize(rosen,
               x0       = np.random.randint(5, size=128),
               method   ="BFGS",
               tol      = 0.01,
               options  = {"maxiter":10, "disp":True},
               callback = minimize_stopper.__call__)
```

Alternatively you can define a class for your minimizer and in it build a callback function to terminate your minimization after a certain time. This can be done like this:

```py
import time
import warnings
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, rosen


class TookTooLong(Warning):
    pass

class Minimizer:
    def __init__(self, timeout, maxiter):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.maxiter = maxiter

    def minimize(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        # minimize
        res = minimize(rosen,
                       x0       = np.random.randint(5, size=128),
                       method   ="BFGS",
                       tol      = 0.01,
                       options  = {"maxiter":self.maxiter, "disp":True},
                       callback = self.callback)
        return res

    def callback(self, x):
        # callback to terminate if max_sec exceeded
        elapsed = time.time() - self.start_time
        if elapsed > self.timeout:
            warnings.warn("Terminating optimization: time limit reached",
                          TookTooLong)
            return True
        else: 
            print("Elapsed: %.3f sec" % elapsed)

# init minimizer and minimize
minimizer = Minimizer(0.1, 100)
result    = minimizer.minimize()
```

Test these code with: `timeout=0.1 & maxiter=100` then `timeout=10 & maxiter=10` to observe both types of termination.