# How terminate the optimization in scipy?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have written a code that has a higher number of initial guess values so it takes a long time to finish the optimization. though after some hours it will nearly converge so I want to stop the optimization that time.

```py
res = minimize(f, x0=x0, bounds=bounds,options={'tol': 1e-6,'maxiter':100})
```

I have implemented `maxiter` but it doesn't work since the number of iterations has crossed and optimization did not stop. so I want to know how `maxiter` is used? I have also seen, as another option, `callback` can be used, but I do not know how? so please help me to solve these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization in scipy.optimize.minimize can be terminated by using *tol* and *maxiter* (*maxfev* also for some optimization methods). There are also some method-specific terminators like *xtol*, *ftol*, *gtol*, etc., as mentioned on scipy.optimize.minimize [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). It is also mentioned that if you don't provide a method then BFGS, L-BFGS-B, or SLSQP is used depending on the problem.

Regarding your first question, you are using the *maxiter* option in the right way, but I can't say why it is not being enforced as you haven't provided an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, the *tol* option is placed in *options* bracket, which is wrong and should be outside of it, like:

`res = minimize(f, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, tol=1e-6,options={'maxiter':100})`

My suggestion would be to look for your problem-specific optimization method on the above-mentioned scipy.optimize.minimize documentation page and use the specific tolerance options.

Regarding your second question, if you want to terminate the optimization after some time, you could do something as follows, which is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252003/scipy-optimize-minimize-does-not-stop-at-maxiter-or-callback) solution proposed by [SuperKogito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6939324/superkogito):

```
from time import time
import warnings
from scipy.optimize import minimize

class TookTooLong(Warning):
    pass

class optimizer():

    def __init__(self, maxtime_sec):
        self.nit = 0
        self.maxtime_sec = maxtime_sec

#    def fun(self, *args):
        # define your function to be minimized here

    def callback(self, x):
        # callback to terminate if maxtime_sec is exceeded
        self.nit += 1
        elapsed_time = time() - self.start_time
        if elapsed_time > self.maxtime_sec:
            warnings.warn("Terminating optimization: time limit reached",
                          TookTooLong)

        else:
            # you could print elapsed iterations and time
            print("Elapsed: %.3f sec" % elapsed_time)
            print("Elapsed iterations: ", self.nit)

    def optimize(self):
        self.start_time = time()
        # set your initial guess to 'x0'
        # set your bounds to 'bounds'
        opt = minimize(self.fun, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, 
                       callback=self.callback, tol=1e-6,options={'maxiter':100})
        return opt

# set maxtime_sec variable to desired stopping time
maxtime_sec = 100
op = optimizer(maxtime_sec)
res = op.optimize()
print(res)
```

You can also use *callback* stop optimization after the desired iteration. However, this is not elegant. Just change the *callback* function in the above code as follows:

```py
class TookTooManyIters(Warning):
    pass

class optimizer():

    def __init__(self, maxtime_sec):
        self.nit = 0
        self.maxtime_sec = maxtime_sec

   # def fun(self, *args):
       # define your function to be minimized here

    def callback(self, x):
        # callback to terminate if desired_iteration is reached
        self.nit += 1
        desired_iteration = 10 # for example you want it to stop after 10 iterations
    
        if self.nit == desired_iteration:
            warnings.warn("Terminating optimization: iteration limit reached",
                          TookTooManyIters)

        else:
            # you could print elapsed iterations, current solution
            # and current function value
            print("Elapsed iterations: ", self.nit)
            print("Current solution: ", x)
            print("Current function value: ", self.fun(x))
```

Comment: indeed I found a way to terminate the optimization in the defined time, but I am looking for a way to terminate it after some iterations that. i do not know why it does not work since even I tried to use maxiter in another optimization, again it has not stopped on that iteration

Comment: You haven't posted a [example] so I also can't tell why it does not work. By the way, you can also use the callback function to terminate the optimization by changing the if condition `if self.nit == desired_iteration`, I am adding this as well in my answer. Also, try to print x (current optimized solution) and your function's current value to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @sadra Did you check the solution after the edited answer? Did it work for you?

Comment: Mosin Khan, sorry for the late, actually maxiter option didn't work again but the execution time worked

Comment: Glad to hear that the execution time solution worked. If my answer solved your question, please see [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).